# pysftp.CnOpts() reports "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pysftp

i am using Python 3.7.0
library pysftp version 0.2.9

i don't know why whenever i run the below command i will have DLL load failed error. It is very annoying as i can't find a easy way to sftp to my remote server using python

**>>> import pysftp

> > > cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()**

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

(base) C:\Users\User>python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pysftp
> > >       cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp__init__.py", line 54, in **init**
> > >           self.hostkeys.load(knownhosts)
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.py", line 97, in load
> > >           e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line, lineno)
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.py", line 360, in from_line
> > >           key = ECDSAKey(data=decodebytes(key), validate_point=False)
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ecdsakey.py", line 168, in **init**
> > >           self.verifying_key = numbers.public_key(backend=default_backend())
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl__init__.py", line 7, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 62, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
> > >         File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 14, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
> > >       **ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
> > >       **

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened to me, seems like an issue with cryptography library, reinstalling it fixed it for me. You can re-install it using pip:

```
pip install cryptography --force-reinstall
```